# Calculate the limit of: $x_n = \frac{\ln(1+\sqrt{n}+\sqrt[3]{n})}{\ln(1 + \sqrt[3]{n} + \sqrt[4]{n})}$, $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

Is it ok to solve the following problem this way? What I have done is to solve parts of the limit first (that converges to $0$), and then solve the remaining expression? Or is this flawed reasoning?

**Question**

Calculate the limit of:

$$x_n = \frac{\ln(1+\sqrt{n}+\sqrt[3]{n})}{\ln(1 + \sqrt[3]{n} + \sqrt[4]{n})}$$

when $n$ goes to infinity.

**Answer**

This can also be written as:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(1+\sqrt{n}+\sqrt[3]{n})}{\ln(1 + \sqrt[3]{n} + \sqrt[4]{n})}$$

The denominator can be written as:

$$\ln(1 + \sqrt[3]{n} + \sqrt[4]{n}) = \ln(1 + \frac{1 + \sqrt[4]{n}}{\sqrt[3]{n}}) + \ln(\sqrt[3]{n})$$

From this we can see that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln(1 + \frac{1 + \sqrt[4]{n}}{\sqrt[3]{n}}) \rightarrow 0$$

The numerator can be written as:

$$\ln(1 + \sqrt{n} + \sqrt[3]{n}) = \ln(1 + \frac{1 + \sqrt[3]{n}}{\sqrt{n}}) + \ln(\sqrt{n})$$

From this we can see that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln(1 + \frac{1 + \sqrt[3]{n}}{\sqrt{n}}) \rightarrow 0$$

This means that we have the following limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(\sqrt{n})}{\ln(\sqrt[3]{n})} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(n^{\frac{1}{2}})}{\ln(n^{\frac{1}{3}})} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{2}\ln(n)}{\frac{1}{3}\ln(n)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3 \ln(n)}{2\ln(n)} \rightarrow \frac{3}{2}$$

The limit converges towards $\frac{3}{2}.$

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Potentially dangerous. Slightly more easily, you could have written it out in a safer form.

Comment: @AndréNicolas please explain what you mean, feel free to provide an answer that clarify the potential error. That would be much appreciated.

Comment: You got the right answer!

Comment: @LukasArvidsson: David's answer explains the issue very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is correct but I would say the working is not quite rigorous.  In effect you have said that
$$\lim a=0\ ,\quad \lim c=0$$
implies
$$\lim\frac{a+b}{c+d}=\lim\frac bd\ .$$
It's true in this case since $b,d\to\infty$; it would also be true if $b,d$ have any finite non-zero limits; but it is not always true if $b,d\to0$.

For example, it is not true that
$$\lim\frac{\frac1n+\frac2n}{\frac1n+\frac3n}=\lim\frac{0+\frac2n}{0+\frac3n}\ .$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer @David, this makes sense. How would you approach this problem instead?

Comment: L'Hopital's rule is probably the easiest way.

Comment: @David: I don't agree with L'Hospital being particularly easy in this particullar case…

Comment: @Bernard I didn't say "easy", I said "easiest".  Can you suggest a simpler fully rigorous method?

Comment: Well… equivalents. Seriously, I always was taught L'Hospital should be avoided, as there are some conditions for its validity that students generally forget. And it is equivalent to Taylor's expansion at order $1$

Answer (score 4):

It is much shorter using *equivalents*:

$1+\sqrt n+\sqrt[3]n\sim_\infty\sqrt n$, hence $\;\ln(1+\sqrt n+\sqrt[3]n)\sim_\infty\frac12\ln(n)$.

Similarly, $\ln(1+\sqrt[3] n+\sqrt[4]n)\sim_\infty\frac13\ln(n)$, whence
$$\frac{\ln(1+\sqrt n+\sqrt[3]n)}{\ln(1+\sqrt[3] n+\sqrt[4]n)}\sim_\infty\frac{\frac12\ln(n)}{\frac13\ln(n)}=\frac32.$$

Comment: I always wonder why people don't suggest this approach, it seems the most straight forward way to get to the result. Is there a reason?

Comment: That is a beautiful solution @Bernard . Thank you! One other way would be to divide by the dominating term. But I am unsure of how to do that when all terms are enclosed in the $\ln$ function. How would you do that?

Comment: You get a log of the dominating term , plus a log which tends to log 1=0. But using equivalence sets this as having been done once and for all. In other words, it avoids you reinvent the wheel each time.

Comment: @jim The reason is that it is not always correct, and in fact the imprecision is the same as in the original question.  It works here because $n^{1/2},n^{1/3}\to\infty$.  But consider$$f=e^{1/n}\ ,\quad g=e^{2/n}\ ;$$then $f\sim g$ is true but $\ln f\sim\ln g$ is false.  Having said that, the method given here is very good as long as you are careful, and it is the method I used first to check the OP's answer.

Comment: Yes there is one restriction to composition by log in equivalents: the function must not approach the value $1$. The only good full reference I know on the web is the French Wikipedia page [Opérations sur les équivalents](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Op%C3%A9rations_sur_les_%C3%A9quivalents).

Comment: I am still quite unsure of what the dominating term in the expression $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(1+\sqrt{n}+\sqrt[3]{n})}{\ln(1 + \sqrt[3]{n} + \sqrt[4]{n})}$ would be. How would you do that division to compare terms?

Comment: It is the term with greatest exponent, as with polynomials (for instance, set $t=n^{1/6}$ in the numerator).

Answer (score 3):

With all due respect to the answers already posted, I'm not in favor of using "equivalents" without enough explanation, or writing $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ before the limit has been shown to exist. Instead, I would do this: The expression for $n>1$ is less than

$$\frac{\ln (3n^{1/2})}{\ln n^{1/3}} = \frac{\ln 3 + (1/2)\ln n}{(1/3)\ln n} = \frac{\ln 3}{(1/3)\ln n} + \frac{3}{2} \to \frac{3}{2}.$$

Similarly, the expression is greater than

$$\frac{\ln n^{1/2}}{\ln (3n^{1/3})} = \frac{(1/2)\ln n}{\ln 3 +(1/3)\ln n}  = \frac{(1/2)}{(\ln 3)/\ln n +(1/3)} \to \frac{3}{2}.$$

By the squeeze theorem, the limit is $3/2.$

Comment: this is even better than using algebraic manipulations (see my answer). +1

Comment: Thank you! this was a nice solution that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try the usual approach of standard limits. We have
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log(1 + \sqrt{n} + \sqrt[3]{n})}{\log(1 + \sqrt[3]{n} + \sqrt[4]{n})}\notag\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{\log\sqrt{n} + \log\left(1 + \dfrac{1 + \sqrt[3]{n}}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}{\log\sqrt[3]{n} + \log\left(1 + \dfrac{1 + \sqrt[4]{n}}{\sqrt[3]{n}}\right)}\tag{1}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{\dfrac{\log n}{2} + \log\left(1 + \dfrac{1 + \sqrt[3]{n}}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}{\dfrac{\log n}{3} + \log\left(1 + \dfrac{1 + \sqrt[4]{n}}{\sqrt[3]{n}}\right)}\notag\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{\log n}\cdot\log\left(1 + \dfrac{1 + \sqrt[3]{n}}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{3} + \dfrac{1}{\log n}\cdot\log\left(1 + \dfrac{1 + \sqrt[4]{n}}{\sqrt[3]{n}}\right)}\tag{2}\\
&= \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2} + 0\cdot 0}{\dfrac{1}{3} + 0\cdot 0}\tag{3}\\
&= \frac{3}{2}\notag
\end{align}
Note that we can not go from step $(1)$ to step $(3)$ directly by just replacing the $\log$ expressions with their limits because replacing a sub-expression by its limit is justified only in two scenarios:

1. When the sub-expression is connected to the rest of the expression *in additive manner*.
2. When the sub-expression is connected to the rest of the expression *in multiplicative manner* and its *limit is non-zero*.

We have instead done a further simplification by dividing numerator and denominator by $\log n$. By doing this we ensure that each term in numerator and denominator has a well defined limit and we can apply algebra of limits to get the final limit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Greatly appreciated since this was probably the way i was expected to solve the problem.